# Linearity from fractional equation? (solar cell)

Tags: electromagnetism, visible-light, electricity, power, distance

I am doing a little research into solar cells, namely the fill factor. It is a ratio, defined as maximum power divided by theoretical power [of the solar cell].

The maximum power and theoretical power fall off with the inverse square of the distance, as should be from the inverse square law. However I am getting a linear fall off on the fill factor with increasing distance.

Does anyone have an idea why/can explain this ?

Comment: can u plz show your calculation of the fill factor thats giving the posited fall off? ratio of two quantities both of which fall of in the same manner shouldn't fall off at all

Comment: Apparently, the maximum power falls off more quickly than the theoretical power for this to hold, but in a manner or because of reasons I have absolutely no clue, to give almost perfect linearity. The equations also go like this. Fill factor = P_max/P_theoretical = I_max * U_max / ( I_sc * U_oc)  Where I_max is the maximum current, U_max the maximum voltage, I_sc the short-circuit current, U_oc the open-circuit voltage. The further equations for those are quite complex which I used fits for

Comment: What distance are you talking about? Fill factor should increase for increasing irradiance on the cell. This is the reason concentrating photovoltaics have higher efficiencies than non-concentrating. Model a solar cell as an ideal diode plus photocurrent and you will see why.

Comment: The distance from a lightsource to a solar cell, the light intensity falls off with the inverse square law, so the short circuit current and the maximum current does so as well, because they are proportional to the intensity. When you move a solar cell away from a lightbulb, the power generated will decrease because less photons hit it. I'm talking about a little lab experiment I did